# How to add a JPanel in a JScrollPanel and then add in a JPanel again?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jscrollpane

Now I have searched around stackoverflow and I can't find anyone asking the same question.

I have a JPanel where I have a JScrollPane with a JPanel inside.
I'm trying to add a JButton to the JPanel inside the JScrollPane, and it worked before I added the JScrollPane to the code.

The problem is that the JButton ain't showing anymore.

My code for that section is:

```
//----- Second Panel -----
JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
secondPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1, false));
secondPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

//----- Upgrade Scroll Pane -----
JScrollPane upgradeScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
upgradeScrollPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,1,false));

//----- Upgrade Panel -----
JPanel upgradePanel = new JPanel();
upgradePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(44,5));

//----- Reinforced index finger -----
Upgrades.rifButton = new JButton();
loadImage(Upgrades.rifButton, "resources/Upgrades/Cursor/Reinforced index finger.png");
Upgrades.rifButton.addActionListener(e -> Upgrades.rif());
Upgrades.rifButton.setToolTipText("Test");
upgradePanel.add(Upgrades.rifButton);

//Adding Upgrade Panel in Upgrade Scroll Pane
upgradeScrollPane.add(upgradePanel);

//Adding Upgrade Scroll Pane in Second Panel
secondPanel.add(upgradeScrollPane);
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

And yes it's a copy of cookie clicker, I'm just trying to learn by doing :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
upgradeScrollPane.add(upgradePanel);
```

This is the wrong approach. Instead either set the view port of the `JScrollPane` or alternately add the component on construction.